# Click event and for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML code:

```
<div class="test" id="inner1">
  ONE
</div>
<div class="test" id="inner2">
  TWO
</div>
<div class="test" id="inner3">
  THREE
</div>

<div class="test1" id="outer1">
  ONE
</div>
<div class="test1" id="outer2">
  TWO
</div>
<div class="test1" id="outer3">
  THREE
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  for (var i=1;i<=3;i++)
  {
     $("#inner"+i).click(function () {  
        $("#outer"+i).css("background-color","blue")
     });
  }  
</script>
```

and the CSS:

```
.test{
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.test1{
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

What I want is to change background color of outer1 by clicking on inner1, change background color of outer2 by clicking on inner2 and change background color of outer3 by clicking on inner3. The above code does not work since it looks for outer4 (i=4) which does not exist when event click is triggered... Do you have any idea how to implement the above with some kind of loop?

Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/Lpwmyspo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate like that, the `i` inside the click function isn't evaluated until you actually click something, and at that time the loop has finished and the value of `i` is the last thing it was set to in the loop.

The real question is why you're using a loop to begin with when you can use the attribute-starts-with selector and `this` instead

```
$('[id^="inner"]').on('click', function () {  
    $('#outer' + this.id.slice(-1)).css("background-color","blue");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpwmyspo/4/)

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
$(".test").on("click", function() {
    var which = this.id.replace(/^inner/, "outer");
    $(".test1").css("background-color","transparent"); // in case you need to reset the background
    $("#" + which).css("background-color","blue");
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/297fxtga/)

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the following way:

```
    <div class="test" id="inner1" onclick="abc(this)">
      ONE
    </div>
    <div class="test" id="inner2" onclick="abc(this)">
      TWO
    </div>
    <div class="test" id="inner3" onclick="abc(this)">
      THREE
    </div>

    <div class="test1" id="outer1">
      ONE
    </div>
    <div class="test1" id="outer2">
      TWO
    </div>
    <div class="test1" id="outer3">
      THREE
    </div>
```

and the JavaScript part as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function abc(e){
        var id = e.id;
        var lastchar = id.substr(id.length -1);
        document.getElementById("outer"+lastchar).style.backgroundColor='blue';

  }  
</script>
```